# chain A s.t. $|X|<|A|\leq |P(X)|$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Can we prove that there exists at least one chain $A$ in P(X), where X is a non-empty set (finite or infinite), s.t. $ |X|<|A|\leq |P(X)|$?

If you can't solve it, ideas/possible directions are welcome :)

The two links mentioned above do not contain answers.

Comment: Do you also want the inequality given in the title? Is $X$ finite? What is $k$?

Comment: If $X$ is finite, we may assume $X=\{1,…,n\}$. Let $A:=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\},…,\{1,2,…,n-1\}, \{1,…,n\}\}$. Then $A$ is a chain of length $n+1$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for infinite.

Comment: The "in other words" part is stating a different problem. Please make a precise question.

Comment: I meant $|A|\leq |P(X)|$

Comment: What is $A$? Is it the chain?

Comment: So the condition $|A|\le |P(X)|$ is not necessary...

Comment: A is a chain in P(X)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Don't you mean $|X| + 1$ (as per example further up)?

Comment: @Tobias: Oh yeah, I forgot about the empty set. :-)

Comment: I removed my (wrong) answer, but the OP gave there in the comment the following reference which might be useful: math.stackexchange.com/questions/90946/uncountable-chains

Comment: If we assume GCH, it follows that there is a chain A with $|A|=2^{|X|}$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90946/uncountable-chains.

Comment: If you are curious,the original question is at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628537/fpx-to-x-property

Comment: can you guys give me some possible direction? Thanks

Comment: Here is the answer:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628537/fpx-to-x-property

Answer (score 0):

All we need to prove is that there exists a chain A in P(X) with $|A|>|X|$ so that at least two of it's elements have to map to the same one.

If X is finite, we may assume $X=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and so $A=\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{1,2\},...,X\}$,which has $|A|=n+1$.

If X is countable then we may assume $X=\{1,2,...\}$. 
One example is the chain of the sets we get from repeated Dedekind cuts adopted from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90946/uncountable-chains). From $|P(\omega)|=2^{\aleph_{0}}=|\mathbb{R}|$ and $|\omega|=\aleph_{0}=|\mathbb{Q}|\Rightarrow$ we set a isomorphism between them. We associate to $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the pair $(A_{x},B_{x})$,where $A_{x}=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}:r\leq x\}$ and $B_{x}=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}:x<r\}$. Thus, $x\leq y\Rightarrow A_{x}\subseteq A_{y}$. This chain has $|\{A_{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{R}}|=2^{\aleph_{0}}$ and so from the isomorphism we get a chain of sets in $P(\omega)$

I am not sure for the uncountable.

For $|X|= \aleph_{1}$, since $2^{\aleph_{0}}\geq \aleph_{1}$,we can use the same chain from the countable case extended to a maximal chain so that $|A|>\aleph_{1}$.