# uncountable well-ordered chain in $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$ without $AC$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

If we assume $AC$ we can construct an uncountable well-ordered chain of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ by well-ordering the reals and then using the same Dedekind's cut construction as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182145/finding-an-uncountable-chain-of-subsets-the-integers).

edit: as pointed out in the comments and Asaf's answer the construction above doesn't work

What if we don't assume $AC$? Can we show the existence of an uncountable, well-ordered chain of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ in $ZF$ alone?

Comment: No, we can't, because it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\omega_1$ does not inject into $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: Note that there's a slight ambiguity here: when you say "well-ordered chain," do you mean "a chain which can be well-ordered" or "a chain whose $\subseteq$-ordertype is well-ordered"? Note that uncountable instances of the latter **can't** happen, even with AC: if $A_\eta\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for $\eta<\omega_1$ with $\alpha<\beta$ implies $A_\alpha\subsetneq A_\beta$, then for each successor $\alpha<\omega_1$ there is some $n_\alpha\in A_\alpha\setminus\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} A_\beta$. Since there are uncountably many successor ordianls but only countably many naturals, this can't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing well-ordered with well-orderable.

There is no uncountable well-ordered chain in $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, because if there was such $\{A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$, map $\alpha$ to the least $n$ in $A_{\alpha+1}\setminus A_\alpha$, and you got yourself an injection from $\omega_1$ into $\omega$. Something which you cannot get with or without choice.

But it is also consistent without the axiom of choice that there is no uncountable well-orderable chain in $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, as it is consistent that there is no injection from $\omega_1$ into $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ which means every well-orderable subset is countable. So we cannot prove in $\sf ZF$ the existence of an uncountable well-orderable subset of $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, chain or otherwise.

Comment: Note that this argument only works for **successor** $\alpha<\omega_1$ (since we could have $A_\lambda=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda} A_\beta$) - but that's still enough.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it also works for the chain $\{\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ which has order type $\omega$. :-) Are you claiming $\omega$ is a successor ordinal? :-P

Comment: Whoops, I read the argument as ". . . the least natural number *in $A_\alpha$* which . . ." Silly me!

Comment: This is interesting. We had been discussing in chat that one should get such a chain by the same construction as in the linked question by first picking a well-ordering of the reals. But what fails is that we are no longer guaranteed that any open interval contains rationals (in fact, this shows that in any well-ordering of the reals there will be an open interval containing no rationals, and same if we replace the rationals by any countable subset. Quite interesting).

Comment: Aha! So that's why this construction fails, interesting. @Asaf When you say that there are no well-ordered chains in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ you're speaking about uncountable chains, right?

Comment: @Alessandro: Yes, thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think this argument still needs a bit of work: we could for instance have $0\not\in\bigcup A_\alpha$, so that $A_\alpha$ always gets mapped to $0$. This is easily fixed (WLOG assume $\bigcup A_\alpha=\mathbb{N}$) but more problematically the map could still be constant for long periods of time. So all this really gets is a cofinal map from $\omega$ to $\omega_1$, which could exist in ZF. I think we do want to look at the least natural in $A_\alpha$ not in any prior $A_\beta$, and to restrict to successor $\alpha$s so that this works. Thoughts?

Comment: @Noah: You're right about the first part. I'm not sure about the second. If you map $\alpha$ to the least $n$ which wasn't used thus far, and does not appear in any previous set, you should get an injection into $\omega$. You're right about successors being the easy way out, though. Map $\alpha$ to the least element in $A_{\alpha+1}\setminus A_\alpha$, and you definitely get an injection into $\omega$.

Answer (score -2):

There is none since the set of integers is countable. The dedekind cut produces an uncountable chain which isn't well ordered.

Comment: Countability of integers doesn't imply that there are no such chains.

Comment: The OP is not asking for the chain to be well-ordered according to $\subseteq$, just that it be well-orderable in some way; see my comment to the question.